# Yii2: kartik/DateTimePicker prevent selection of a date before today

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I have tried with below code and it is not working for me.

```
echo $form->field($model, 'value')->widget(DateTimePicker::classname(), [
      'pluginOptions' => [
           'autoclose'      => true,
           'format'         => 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:ii:ss',
           'minuteStep'     => 1,
           'todayHighlight' => true,
           'startDate'      => date("y-m-d H:i:s"),
           'changeYear'     => true,
           'changeMonth'    => true,
      ]
])->label('Select date & time');
```

Comment: See, whether you restrict from here or there. User Can modify date time picker textbox values before submitting form. So, you have to restrict it through **model** file.

Comment: I want to restrict from both model and widget.

Comment: Wait a minute. You can change your textbox values in datetime picker by manually changing the date. So, you have to follow model validation first. Any one can disable client validation .

Comment: See, here my requirement is disable previous date selection from today.

Comment: Add `'minDate' => 0,`. It will disable previous date selection from today

Comment: if i m not wrong you are using the `\kartik\widgets\DateTimePicker` ?

Answer (score 2):

It works for me as below:

```
$form->field($model, 'value')->widget(DateTimePicker::classname(), [
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter Value'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true,
        'format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
        'startDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `'minDate' => 0` to **disable** previous date selection from today.

**Updated Code**

```
echo $form->field($model, 'value')->widget(DateTimePicker::classname(), [
      'pluginOptions' => [
           'autoclose'      => true,
           'format'         => 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:ii:ss',
           'minuteStep'     => 1,
           'minDate'        => 0,
           'todayHighlight' => true,
           'startDate'      => date("y-m-d H:i:s"),
           'changeYear'     => true,
           'changeMonth'    => true,
      ]
])->label('Select date & time');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  echo $form->field($model, 'value')->widget(DateTimePicker::classname(), [
          'pluginOptions' => [
               'minuteStep'     => 1,
               'minDate'        => 0,
               'startDate'      => date("y-m-d H:i:s"),
          ]
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following i assume you are using `kartik\widgets\DateTimePicker`

```
$form->field($model, 'campaign_schedule', [
    'inputOptions' =>
    [
        'value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    ],
])->widget(kartik\widgets\DateTimePicker::class, [
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select operating time ...'],
    'convertFormat' => false,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss',
        'todayHighlight' => true,
        'startDate' => new JsExpression("new Date('" . date('m/d/y') . "')"),
        'autoclose' => true,
    ],
])
```